# Correctly generating AWS auth headers from temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have an API Gateway that has two endpoints:

1. Authorization type is `NONE`. Delegates to a lambda named `fooLambda`.
2. Authorization type is `AWS_IAM`.

The client is supposed to call endpoint 1 to obtain credentials from the `fooLambda` so that they can successfully call endpoint 2.

I am using the AWS Node.js sdk and the `aws4` npm module for signing aws requests. Here is some pseudocode for my `fooLambda`:

```
// get the role using this...
STS.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn of my role that can call endpoint 2',
    RoleSessionName: 'foobar',
})

// parse the sts creds like this....
const stsCredentials = STS.credentialsFrom(assumeRoleResponse)

// get a collection of signed headers like so
const signedHeaders = aws4.sign({
    service: 'execute-api',
    region: process.env.REGION,
}, {
    secretAccessKey: stsCredentials.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: stsCredentials.accessKeyId,
    sessionToken: stsCredentials.sessionToken,
}).headers;

// return the following headers to the client
return {
    authorizationHeader: signedHeaders['Authorization'],
    stsSecurityToken: signedHeaders['X-Amz-Security-Token'],
}
```

Now my intent is that the client can attach these two headers to their requests so that they can successfully call endpoint 2 but I get an error saying that the security token is invalid but I'm not sure why.

UPDATE: When I use Postman's AWS Signature Authorization type and supply my accessKey, secretKey, aws region, service name, and session token parameters - it creates the authorization headers and the request to endpoint 2 is successful!

After inspecting the postman-generated authorization headers, it seems that the Authorization header has a different signature. So now the problem is: "How is postman generating a correct authorization header but aws4 isn't?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `aws4.sign` function, you have to provide the path that the request will have. Otherwise there is a mismatch between the signed request and the actual request that is made and AWS will barf.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You must attach the following policy **AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess** a your users, maybe also you can create a user group and attach that policy.

**2.** **Just for discard,** create a new method (endpoint) without authentication, something like:

```
    https://uid.execute-api.regionidentifier.amazonaws.com/test/ping
```

So, we're discarding any issue related with apigateway.

Once having the method "ping" implemented, you can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) for test it.

**3.** Verify that **AWS_IAM_AUTH** is working in your method (endpoint).

So, i've found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfoKFaHisbY) that it can be very helpful for test your endpoint with auth header.

Good luck, tell me later how it went.

Comment: I don't have the `AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess` policy attached to the user. I have a more fine-grained `execute-api` policy on the second endpoint. It still is not working. I still get an error saying `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.` so I don't know what's wrong with my code.